# FlexSDK to compile mxml file

Tags: lex

Downloaded and installed the latest version of a FlexSDK. Unzipped it into a folder C:FlexSDK. Opened up my command prompt to C:/FlexSDK/bin.  Ran a directory of the folder and my mxmlc.exe file was there.  From the command prompt I issued mxmlc c:test.mxml and received a **"could not find a JVM"** error. This is surprising because I have compiled mxml files from the command prompt on my computer before.  Also I have developed, compiled, and ran java programs before from the command prompt.  I know I have a JRE on my system. As a matter of fact it is located at "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6".  As I stated earlier I have compiled mxml files a while back. I dont understand what the problem might be now.

Answer (score 6):

From http://jonemerson.net/blog/?m=200607 and http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2842

> It turns out that if you’re on Windows
>   and you have JAVA_HOME defined using
>   backslashes, it will not work. 
>   Instead you must set JAVA_HOME using
>   forward slashes in your environment
>   variables, or create a jvm.config file
>   next to mxmlc.exe containing the line
>   “java.home=c:/j2sdk1.4.2_12″(or
>   equivalent).

Note this is the path to the JDK not the JRE. Something like `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_11`

Comment: In my java.home = in my jvm.config file, should I have the directory to where my Java is located: c:/Program Files/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin

OR

the directory to where my FlexSDK is located: c:/FlexSDK/java

JM

Comment: java.home = c:/Program Files/java/jdk1.6.0_20 should be it.

Answer (score 0):

In `java.config` file `jre` path should be with forward `/` like

```
java.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/jre
```